# What is wrong in my bibtex entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to cite a paper whose bibtex entry is generated via Google scholar. I am using biblatex to manage my bibliography, however, when trying to compile
with xelatex, I got the following error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.10 \printbibliography[title=References]

? ! Missing } inserted.
```

It seems that there is some error in the bibtex entry.

A minimum latex file "see.tex" that reproduces this error is

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{paper.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Yan2013}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

And the content in `paper.bib` is:

```
@article{Yan2013, 
    author={Z. Yan and P. I. Mak and M. K. Law and R. P. Martins}, 
    journal={IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits}, 
    title={A 0.016-mm$^{2}$ 144-$\mu$W Three-Stage Amplifier Capable of Driving 1-to-15 nF Capacitive Load With $>$ 0.95-MHz GBW}, 
    year={2013}, 
    volume={48}, 
    number={2}, 
    pages={527-540}, 
    keywords={UHF amplifiers;circuit feedback;compensation;GBW;capacitance 1 nF to 15 nF;capacitive load;control-centric method;current-buffer Miller compensation;figure-of-merit;frequency 0.95 MHz;local feedback loop analysis;minimum gain-bandwidth product;parasitic-pole cancellation;pole-zero placements;power 144 muW;size 0.35 mum;slew rate;small-signal FOM;three-stage amplifier;Circuit analysis;Feedback loop;Limiting;Poles and zeros;Stability analysis;Standards;Active LHP zero;CMOS;Miller compensation;current buffer;current buffer Miller compensation;frequency compensation;pole-zero cancellation;three-stage amplifier}, 
    doi={10.1109/JSSC.2012.2229070}, 
    ISSN={0018-9200}, 
    month={Feb},
}
```

I compile my latex file with the following command:

```
xelatex see
biber see
xelatex see
```

So, what is wrong with the content in "paper.bib"? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Never trust automatic bibliography export tools. Always check if the result makes sense. In this case, the hyphens in the title are more than suspicious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title is the problem. The casing is changed from title to sentence style and this breaks `\mu`. This can be prevented by using curly braces to protect the problematic parts of the title and, where the letter case should not be changed, e.g. the units.

Example:

```
title={A 0.016-mm{$^{2}$} 144-{$\mu$W} Three-Stage Amplifier Capable of Driving 1-to-15 {nF} Capacitive Load With $>$ 0.95-{MHz} {GBW}},
```

> [image: Result]

If it is acceptable to add a package dependency to the bibliography data (`paper.bib`), then the numbers with unit can be set with package `siunitx`,
see Mico's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405257/what-is-wrong-in-my-bibtex-entry/405258?noredirect=1#comment1010176_405258).
This requires that the document loads the package:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

The `title` entry becomes:

```
title={A
  {\SI[output-decimal-marker=., number-unit-product=-]{0.016}{\milli\meter\squared}}
  {\SI[number-unit-product=-]{144}{\micro\watt}}
  Three-Stage Amplifier Capable of Driving
  {\SIrange[range-units=single, range-phrase=-to-]{1}{15}{\nano\farad}}
  Capacitive Load With
  {\SI[output-decimal-marker=., number-unit-product=-]{>0.95}{\mega\hertz}}
  {GBW}},
```

Remarks:

- `\SI` with arguments also needs to be surrounded by curly braces.
- The hyphens in `1-to-15` can be added by option `range-phrase`. The other hyphens between numbers and units are set by option `number-unit-product`.
- Option `output-decimal-marker` is added to prevent that the decimal marker is changed due to other document settings (e.g., if the document is in a different language with different output marker).

Result:

> [image: Result with siunitx]

Comment: Even better than `${\mu$W}` would be `\textmicro{W}` or, if the `siunitx` package is loaded, `SI{0.016}{\milli\meter\squared} \SI{144}{\micro\watt}`.

Comment: I am pretty sure those hyphens are due to a faulty export and should not be in the final result. Rule of thumb: Never trust auto-generated Bib entries.

Comment: @Johannes_B There are several versions of the article. I found a version [ISSCC 2012](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/institute-of-electrical-and-electronics-engineers/a-0-016mm-2-144-w-three-stage-amplifier-capable-of-driving-1-to-15nf-0YuBD54ipa) without the hyphens. But the cited article has the hyphens, see [JSSC 2013](http://repository.umac.mo/bitstream/10692/853/1/9635_0_3-stageamp_JSSC_2013.pdf)

Comment: @Mico or Heiko...  Which kind of problem we have using a quick and dirty solution including all in a couple of additional `{...}` ? In the specific case  `title={{A 0.016-mm$^{2}$ 144-$\mu$W Three-Stage Amplifier Capable of Driving 1-to-15 nF Capacitive Load With $>$ 0.95-MHz GBW}}, `

Comment: @Hastur Then, the automatic conversion of title case to sentence case does not work anymore.